# make textfield not readable and also not writeable

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

I have two text field and on both text field I use a picker view to show the values in drop down. Now, I want the user to only be able to click and select the values shows in picker view. User can't be able to write anything now how can I do this. I already used `BOOL` method in `textField:shouldBeginEditing` but its not working user can write anything from keyboard.so how can I stop them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this and let me know if it works.

```
[theTextField setEnabled: NO];
```